# Group_by + Mutate gives incorrect results with knock-on effect if NAs are present

Tags: r, dplyr

> **dplyr version 0.4.3**

I've stumbled upon a problem whereby using `mutate` on a grouped dataframe in which there is a group containing `NA` values only results in erroneous calculation for **other groups** too. The behaviour certainly seems to be inconsistent with other functions in `dplyr`, and also base R.

#### Reproducible example

**Data**

```
test <- data.frame(id = rep(1:4, each = 2),
                   value = c(NA, NA, 2, 3, 3, 5, 21, 0))
> test
  id value
1  1    NA
2  1    NA
3  2     2
4  2     3
5  3     3
6  3     5
7  4    21
8  4     0
```

**Problem demonstration**

```
mean.mutate <- test %>% 
               group_by(id) %>% 
               mutate(mean = mean(value, na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
               print()

Source: local data frame [8 x 3]
Groups: id [4]

    id value  mean
    (int) (dbl) (dbl)
1     1    NA    NA
2     1    NA    NA
3     2     2   2.5
4     2     3   2.5
5     3     3    NA  # mean should be 4 for this group
6     3     5    NA
7     4    21  10.5
8     4     0  10.5
```

**Alternatives, which do work**

Using `do`:

```
mean.do <- test %>%
           group_by(id) %>% 
           do(mutate(., mean = mean(value, na.rm = TRUE))) %>% 
           print()

    Source: local data frame [8 x 3]
    Groups: id [4]

    id value  mean
    (int) (dbl) (dbl)
1     1    NA   NaN  # notice that NaN is returned, not NA as above
2     1    NA   NaN
3     2     2   2.5
4     2     3   2.5
5     3     3   4.0  # correct
6     3     5   4.0
7     4    21  10.5
8     4     0  10.5
```

Using `summarise`:

```
mean.summary <- test %>% 
                group_by(id) %>% 
                summarise(mean = mean(value, na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
                print()

    Source: local data frame [4 x 2]

    id  mean
    (int) (dbl)
1     1   NaN  # as above
2     2   2.5
3     3   4.0  # correct
4     4  10.5
```

Using base R's `ave`:

```
within(test, mean <- ave(value, id, FUN = function(x) mean(x, na.rm = TRUE)))

id value mean
1  1    NA  NaN  # as above
2  1    NA  NaN
3  2     2  2.5
4  2     3  2.5
5  3     3  4.0  # correct
6  3     5  4.0
7  4    21 10.5
8  4     0 10.5
```

#### Other observations

The error doesn't occur if at least one value is NOT `NA` in the group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Follow-up**
I have submitted this as an [issue](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/1908%22issue%22) on GitHub in the `dplyr` repo. Hadley replied in due course, please see below.

**Solution**
The problem has been rectified in the development version of dplyr (currently `0.4.3.9001` as of 12/06/2015). Although instructions on how to get the development version are included in `README.md` in the repository, the installation will fail with an infinite download/install loop.

Here are the instructions to solve both problems at once (from [issue #1904](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/1904#issuecomment-225236529%22issue%20#1904%22) on GitHub:

```
# 1. Install dev version of 'devtools'
    if (packageVersion("devtools") < 1.6) {
        devtools::install_github("hadley/devtools")
    }

# 2. Restart R session  - IMPORTANT!

# 3. After restart install dev version of both 'lazyeval' and 'dplyr'    
    devtools::install_github("hadley/lazyeval")
    devtools::install_github("hadley/dplyr")
```